# Run automated test cases with base_url as parameter

Tags: ruby, rspec, webdriver

I am using Webdriver in Ruby and I want to write my test cases in a way that i dont need to edit the @base_url (URL) of the test case every time i want to run the test case, because we test the same test in 3 diferent environments, and with my limited knowledge, I can only think of an RSpec Tag with the 3 test cases in only one file for the 3 cases (Its), one for any environment (:testing, :preproduction or :production) but that will bring the issue of having to edit 3 times the same code at every code change.

I would love to know if the rspec Tag options or any sort of parameter can be pass with the rspec command, so i can use a "Case" in the Ruby code and only having 3 lines of code at the beggining and not 3 times the whole test code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using a rakefile with different tasks for different environments. Within the rakefile tasks you could create an ENV variable and read that in your code?

Let me know if you want any help with this, should be doable.

Comment: The present solution I've found, (because I have a lot of time to maintain the automated cases) is to lauch the test suites within a .bat DOS launcher from the command line. But yes, I tried a couple of times to setup Rake with no luck following guides, I'll like to follow a detailed guide to make it work.

Comment: I just had a couple of days to test and learn about Rake. and i had make a rakefile, but don't yet understand how to pass the parameters of the urls and browsers and how to pass them to the ruby test cases.

Comment: How are the tests triggered? You can set environment variables on those systems and reference them within the rake file. To access an environment variable within the rake file, you do ENV['<variable>'] e.g. ENV['BASE_URL']. This means you don't need to faff around with passing arguments to your rake task.

Comment: We run rspec that is called by a bat command under windows, but im now trying to make it run with Rake. I asked another question with more info here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32251355/how-to-use-different-urls-and-browsers-in-webdriver-with-rake-parameters)